# How to append nested dict value in one list to another?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

Suppose I have something like:

```
list1 = [{"l1_key_1": "l1_value_1", "l1_key_2": "l1_value_2", "l1_key_3": "l1_value_3"}, {...}]
list2 = [{"l2_key_1": "l2_value_1", "l2_key_2": "l2_value_2", "l2_key_3": "l2_value_3"}, {...}]
```

I'm trying to get an output similar to:

```
list2 = [{"l2_key_1": ["l1_value_1", "l2_value_1"], "l2_key_2": "l2_value_2", "l2_key_3": "l2_value_3"}, {...}]
```

I've tried using the `zip()` and `defaultdict` methods to help with this but haven't had much luck.

I essentially want to know how I can combine the values of the first and second key for the first element into a list, do the same for the second element, and so on.

Comment: I don't see the logic for how you're combining things. Why is `l2_value_2` in the value of `l2_key_1` in the result?

Comment: While dictionaries in recent versions of Python retain insertion order, you shouldn't depend on it. The logic should be based on keys and values, not order.

Comment: Why doesn't your result have lists as the values for the 2nd and 3rd key?

Comment: Yeah there isn't a pattern here, which is what makes it difficult. I'm just trying to combine the first values of the first key in each list element.

Comment: Is the first `l2_value_2` in the result a typo for `l2_value_1`?

Comment: You only want to combine the values of the first dictionary element, the rest just come from `list2`?

Comment: Ah yes you're right, that's a typo, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copies of the dictionaries from `list2`. Then get the first keys and values from the two dictionaries, combine the values into a list, and replace the first dictionary element with that.

Use a list comprehension to do this for every pair of dictionaries.

```
def combine_dicts(d1, d2):
    first_value1 = list(d1.values())[0]
    first_key, first_value2 = list(d2.entries())[0]
    new_dict = d2.copy()
    new_dict[first_key] = [first_value1, first_value2]
    return new_dict

result = [combine_dicts(d1, d2) for (d1, d2) in zip(list1, list2)]
```

This assumes that the two lists are the same length. If not, the extra elements in one of the lists will be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your output, I see some of the items in the output are lists and some are strings.  I consider this an anti-pattern.  I think it would be better to have all items as list (even if there is only one or zero items in the list).

Here is code to do what I think you're asking:

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_list = []
for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2):
    new_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in d1.items():
        new_dict[k].append(v)
    for k, v in d2.items():
        new_dict[k].append(v)
    
    new_list.append(new_dict)
```

One thing to note is that if list1 and list2 are different sizes, `zip` will only use elements up to the length of the shorter list.  If you insist on having both list and string types in the output, the code will be slightly more complex, but I don't see any benefit to doing that.

Comment: Note: the above code works if the `dict`s in list1 and list2 contain different items.